# Android, concern over VM heap size

Tags: android, bitmap, virtual-machine, heap-memory

After some testing with a completed product, I have just found that the hardware devices I have all have large VM Heaps.

The lowest being 32MB.

My application is a memory intensive application that loads a bunch of high quality, alpha images and draws them to the canvas as an animation. There can be up to two sets of these loaded (one for the current animation and one for the next)

I am now concerned after having decreased the VM Heap Size on one of my devices to 16MB that it won't in fact run on devices with a heap size that small.

Since I can not do much about the size of the images, and there is little I can do to reduce the number of images, I ask how would I go about chieving the same result with less stringent memory restrictions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say high quality, do you mean high resolution?  My suggestion is that you only store in memory what you need to display on screen, and store the rest on the filesystem.  You could then process it in chunks in the background.  Not sure if that'll work for you, I don't really understand what your app does.

Comment: Well, By high quality I mean that the images are all loaded and displayed as ARGB_8888, The other respondants suggestion of scaling them is not useful because all images are created at exactly the size they are required for displaying on the screen. Essentially, the application creates little animations of images. Think of it like I'm creating southpark episodes at runtime. The only images loaded are those for the curent "scene" and when switching to the next I have the images for the current and the next "scene". Images are essentially "parts" of any moving subject in the "scene".

Comment: Accepted on the basis that the solution here was not the method the images are loaded, because either way, they still have to be bitmap decoded, but instead that only the images currently in use need be kept in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to decode the images. It may make them much lighter. Remember that images become bitmaps when they are shown increasing their memory consuption.

```
public static Bitmap decode(byte[] imageByteArray, int width, int height) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0, imageByteArray.length,
            o);

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < width || height_tmp / 2 < height)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    o2.inTempStorage = new byte[Math.max(16 * 1024, width * height * 4)];
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0,
            imageByteArray.length, o2);

    // return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageByteArray, 0,
    // imageByteArray.length);
}
```

where

width  - MAX width in pixels that the imageView might have.
height - MAX height in pixels that the imageView might have.

That way, the bitmap will become lighter and the app might consume less memory.

(NOTE: I copied this method and modified it a little bit, I don't remember the original question so i cant put the url)

I use to strore the images in byte arrays and I only decode them just before showing them.

Now, like James L says, its best to keep the images in the fileSystem and only bring to memory when needed, but if you an't do that (my case). you can download images with:

```
public static byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    int len;
    int size = 1024;
    byte[] buf;

    if (is instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
        size = is.available();
        buf = new byte[size];
        len = is.read(buf, 0, size);
    } else {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        buf = new byte[size];
        while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, size)) != -1)
            bos.write(buf, 0, len);
        buf = bos.toByteArray();
    }
    return buf;
}

public static byte[] downloadFileByteArray(String fileUrl)
            throws IOException, MalformedURLException {

    URL myFileUrl = null;

    myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    return getBytes(is);
}
```

If you allready have the images in memory you will be able to turn them into byte arrays by loking at the methods I present.

Other than that (and calling System.gc()) there is not much you can do (that I know of). Maybe dleting the BMPs in the onPause() and onDestroy() and recostructing them in the onResume() if necesary.

Comment: I had problems with the VM heap size while loading "a bunch of high quality" just like @Hamid explains he is having. I solved it by using this methods. I started storing the images in the ram in jpg fotmat instead of Drawable or Bitmap format, that, of curse, unless the images were being shown at the moment. I made that in oder to reducing the memory consumption. It's not exactly what he is asking for, but it might help to solve his problem. Now modifying the decode method any format instead of byte array should be easy to acomplish. Using that method reduces memory consumption by a lot.

Comment: Surely this only makes things worse? I would not only have to have the bytearray in memory, but also, at the point of displaying the image, the bitmap data for it too. In my standard use-case I have almost, if not all of the images displayed at once.

Comment: When I whote this, I didnt know you were allready displaying only what was needed. I just read the comment you gave to the other answer and in your casi I think its better to save pics on the filesystem. It's a good solution if you are showing a small amount of bitmaps at the same time (and dont want to save pics on the device). With this I've been able to have a 51 picture full-screen gallery on ram, without saving anithing o the device, having pictures of 100kb.

Comment: I just thought about something, there is a way to know the VMHeap in android, I dont remeber it well, but a friend once showed it to me. you might be able to check the heap size and depending on it, have a set of lower quality images to reduce the heap requirements if needed. It's not the best option, but it might let you play the animations on low VM heap devices. It's the best i can come up with. If you want the method to get the VM hep, I might be able to find it, tell me and i'll look for it.